# Serial Measurement Data RS232 interpretation

Tags: serial-port, byte, measurement

I am trying to get readings from an ultrasonic thickness tester without using the included software, but I haven't been able to interpret the measurement readings from the tester.

Below are the hex values that are sent from the tester, and the corresponding decimal value that is displayed in the software.

```
 3A 30 62 30 30 44 39 37 30 30 65 36 0D 0A       1.51
 3A 30 62 30 30 44 66 61 30 30 34 39 0D 0A       2.50
 3A 30 62 30 30 44 37 62 30 31 63 62 0D 0A       3.79
 3A 30 62 30 30 44 38 32 30 31 64 32 0D 0A       3.86
 3A 30 62 30 30 44 63 37 30 31 31 37 0D 0A       4.55
 3A 30 62 30 30 44 39 34 30 62 65 65 0D 0A      29.64
 3A 30 62 30 30 44 39 63 30 62 66 36 0D 0A      29.72
 3A 30 62 30 30 44 63 61 30 62 32 34 0D 0A      30.18
 3A 30 62 30 30 44 65 64 30 62 34 37 0D 0A      30.53
 3A 30 62 30 30 44 38 65 33 65 31 62 0D 0A     160.14
 3A 30 62 30 30 44 64 66 33 65 36 63 0D 0A     160.95
```

Any help on how I get from the hex values to the decimal value would be very much appreciated.

ASCII equivalent (I have omitted CR and LF  which are at the end of each line) :

```
 :0b00D9700e6     1.51
 :0b00Dfa0049     2.50
 :0b00D7b01cb     3.79
 :0b00D8201d2     3.86
 :0b00Dc70117     4.55
 :0b00D940bee    29.64
 :0b00D9c0bf6    29.72
 :0b00Dca0b24    30.18
 :0b00Ded0b47    30.53
 :0b00D8e3e1b   160.14
 :0b00Ddf3e6c   160.95
```

Comment: please post your code. I assume you are using an Arduino?

Comment: No code as yet - just watching the comms between the thickness tester and the program it came with (DATAVIEW for Ultrasonic Thickness Gauge ----V2.2). Not using Arduino, just thickness tester connected to PC.

Comment: I have tried these number formats without any luck: single point float, double point float and pascal 6 byte real float

Comment: The data is obviously ASCII code.  Instead of hex numbers, display the data as ASCII characters.

Comment: Updated question with ASCII code

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out:

The data is the two bytes after :0b00D, LSB first, multiplied by 100.

```
    ASCII        Hex    Decimal
 :0b00D9700e6    0097     1.51
 :0b00Dfa0049    00fa     2.50
 :0b00D7b01cb    017b     3.79
 :0b00D8201d2    0182     3.86
 :0b00Dc70117    01c7     4.55
 :0b00D940bee    0b94    29.64
 :0b00D9c0bf6    0b9c    29.72
 :0b00Dca0b24    0bca    30.18
 :0b00Ded0b47    0bed    30.53
 :0b00D8e3e1b    3e8e   160.14
 :0b00Ddf3e6c    3edf   160.95
```